# three.js dom element makes the whole page gets larger

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, three.js

I'm trying to build a 3D viewer with three.js, that has full height but leaves space for a side panel. The vertical layout works as expected, but as soon as I append the render's dom element, a horizontal scroll bar appears.

Attached is a minimal working example. I would expect to just see the (black) canvas element and the red body. But after `v.append(renderer.domElement)`, the page gets larger (filled with blue, html element) and a horizontal scroll bar appears. It seems the page is larger than its body.

See https://jsfiddle.net/5jnvt4jh.

Has anybody an idea, what may be happening there? I couldn't find any margin or padding with Chrome and Firefox. Thanks :).

#### MWE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            html {
                background-color: blue;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0px;
                height: 100vh;
                background-color: red;
            }

            #viewer {
                height: 100%;
                width: 80vw;
                background-color: green;
            }
        </style>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/86/three.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="viewer"></div>
        <script>
            var v = document.getElementById('viewer');
            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            v.append(renderer.domElement);
            renderer.setSize(v.clientWidth, v.clientHeight);
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to add `overflow: hidden;` to the style of `body`

Answer (score 0):

Change style of body to:

```
body {
            margin: 0px;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: red;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/raushankumar0717/5jnvt4jh/2/